# M-x does not show previous commands

Tags: emacs

Recently I upgraded Emacs from 24 to 25.3.2 version. After automatic installation of all packages by `use-package` I noticed that `M-x` always shows the standard list of all possible commands in alphabetical order. For example, I press `M-x` and type `dired`. Next time I cannot press `M-x` and just run a previous command, I have to type `dired` again.

I have no idea which package forces `M-x` to behave in that way.

I was not so sure where to ask this question: here or in [emacs.stackexchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/). It seems, in stackoverflow there are also a lot of emacs questions.

Comment: Say how you are trying to "run a previous command". Do you see the problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: You can post an Emacs question here or at emacs.SE. (But please don't post the same question to both.) On SO you might get more programmer eyes. On SE you might get more Emacs expertise.

Comment: @Drew,  It was caused by `counsel` package and for counsel it is the standard way to show all commands after `M-x`. Installing `smex` package solved the problem.

Comment: Note that there's a fork of `smex` called `amx`: https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/amx